# Java Check if a method is still running

Tags: java, function, process, binance

I have a problem. I am using the Binance API in my project. With this API I open a candlestick stream to receive the newest update of different candlestick periods. The candlestick stream method is in a class that looks like this:

```
public class CandlestickStream {

    private String market;
    private String coin;
    private String period;

    public CandlestickStream(String market, String coin, String period) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        this.market = market;
        this.coin = coin;
        this.period = period;

        startCandlestickEventStreaming();
      }


    /**
     * Starting a stream to get the current candlestick data of the given symbol and period
     * @param symbol The symbol you want the data from
     * @param interval The period of the candlestick
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws SecurityException
     */
    public void startCandlestickEventStreaming() throws SecurityException, IOException {

        BinanceApiWebSocketClient client = BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance().newWebSocketClient();

        String symbol = createSymbolString(market, coin);
        CandlestickInterval interval = periodToInterval(period);

        client.onCandlestickEvent(symbol, interval, response -> {

            System.out.println(response);

        });

    }

}
```

The stream gets started using the following code:

```
// Loop over every market-coin-period combination and start the firstrun and stream
for (String market : markets) {
    for (String coin : coins) {
        for (String period : periods) {

            // Run candlestick stream to monitor if it's still running
            new CandlestickStream(market, coin, period);             

        }
    }
}
```

But I noticed that binance could restart the server which causes the stream function to stop and then I won't receive any updates without any errors. So I need a way to check whether the function is still running. If not, I need to restart it. What is the best way to have control on a process to check if it is still running and if not, then restart the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say when you Open the Stream create a DB entry (status = INIT_READ). And once done update the status (DONE_READ). The way batch jobs works.

And you can create a Scheduler to Check the status of that Entry after every X amount of time.

By that status check on server start you can take the decision what you need to do.

Comment: Okay, I will take a look at that. But just to make sure you understand what I need to do.... The stream runs 24/7, I just need to make sure that it is still running. If not, I need to restart the stream. The stream can end, because the binance servers are restarting or the server loses connection. Is this the best approach then?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the stream is never done, so using a status doesn't work I think, or I understand you wrong?

Comment: Ohhk, in that case I would say you should surround your call with try-finally. So when method is exited it will go inside finally. And there you can do your operation to recall/restart it.

Comment: What should I surround with a try-finally? The entire class creation: `new CandlestickStream(market, coin, period);` or inside the class the: `startCandlestickEventStreaming();`?

Comment: In my opinion  new CandlestickStream(market, coin, period);       should work. But you can give it a try as per your requirement.